# Daemon to know when a user logs into the MAC

Tags: macos, cocoa, launch-daemon

I have a daemon (written in Obj C) running, and I would like to perform some action when some user logs in. Is it possible for a Daemon to know when a particular user logs in or out in OSX? Are there any Notifications thrown when a log in occurs? I would like to avoid the use of Log in Item or Launch Agent. And also i would like to avoid polling on a timer to check the logged in user.

Comment: How can a program be both a daemon and a Cocoa app?

Comment: i intended that it is written in Obj C.. editing the Ques

Comment: That's a good question.  Can you confirm that your daemon is in the *root session* (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/SystemContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002208-BCICFCJH)?

Comment: trojanfoe: Yes it is in the root session

Comment: Hi @ShantiK, can you share your daemon project that gets the username?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser` to get the console user name.

```
CFStringRef  consoleUserName = nil;
uid_t        uid;
gid_t        gid;
consoleUserName = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(NULL, &uid, &gid);
```

Store `consoleUserName` in some member variable.
Now creates a session to interact with the dynamic store maintained by the System Configuration server using `SCDynamicStoreCreate`

```
     SCDynamicStoreRef   store;
     CFStringRef         key;
     CFArrayRef          keys;
     CFRunLoopSourceRef  rls;
     store = SCDynamicStoreCreate(
                                     NULL, 
                                     CFSTR("com.apple.dts.ConsoleUser"), 
                                     callBackFunction, 
                                     NULL
                                     );

    // Set it up to notify us when the console user value changes.

    key = SCDynamicStoreKeyCreateConsoleUser(NULL);
    assert(key != NULL);

    keys = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **) &key, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    //assert(keys != NULL);

    success = SCDynamicStoreSetNotificationKeys(store, keys, NULL);
    //assert(success);

    // Add it to the runloop.

    rls = SCDynamicStoreCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, store, 0);
   // assert(rls != NULL);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), rls, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);


    mConsoleUserName = CopyCurrentConsoleUsername(store);
    CFRunLoopRun();

    CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate(rls);
    CFRelease(rls);
    CFRelease(keys);
    CFRelease(key);
    CFRelease(store);
```

Implement `callBackFunction` function. You will get callback when the console user value changes.

```
static void callBackFunction(
                               SCDynamicStoreRef    store,
                               CFArrayRef          changedKeys,
                               void *              info
                               )
{
    CFStringRef         currentConsoleUser;
    Boolean             didChange;

    // Get the current console user.

    currentConsoleUser = CopyCurrentConsoleUsername(store);

    if (currentConsoleUser == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    didChange = ! CFEqual(storedvalue, currentConsoleUser);
    if (![currentConsoleUser isEqualToString:@"loginwindow"])
    {
      // pass this value to some method
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not necessarily that the log in user changes. I would like to be notified even if the same user logs out and logs in back again

Comment: You can modify callBackFunction as per your requirements. You will get call Back when user logout and login.

Comment: When user logout you will get notification that console user changed to "loginWindow". for login you will get notification that console user is changed to "loginwindow" to "Some user"

Comment: Oh ok.. for some reason, it doesn't seem to work for me. I will check further

Comment: or Have a look at [Multiple User Environment Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/BPMultipleUsers.pdf)